# Как удалить точку, но только если после нее вместе идет любой символ кроме пробела и переноса строки?

Tags: php

Есть строка вида:

> Тест строка, .еще один? пример .строки тест.

Нужно удалить точку только перед словом `.еще` и `.строки`

Буду благодарен за информацию!

Comment: Обычно перед точками нет пробела. Поэтому можно проверять, если перед точкой есть пробел, то удалять ее

Comment: @ВиталийШебаниц а если после точки будет пробел? Вы её тоже удалите

Comment: preg_replace(‘/\.(^\s\n)*/‘, ‘’, ‘Тест строка, .еще один? пример .строки тест.’). Правда, тут он удаляет и последнюю точку.

Comment: @Alpha во первых не вижу варианта, где после точки есть пробел, во вторых, по логике того, что написал, то если перед точкой есть пробе и поосле - то да, она удалится.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Получилось такое регулярное выражение `/(\.)+(?!(\s)|(\n)|($))/`

Используя функцию `preg_replace()`:

```php
$str = 'Тест строка, .еще один? пример .строки тест.';
$str = preg_replace("/(\.)+(?!(\s)|(\n)|($))/", '', $str);

return $str; // Returns 'Тест строка, еще один? пример строки тест.'
```

---

- `(\.)+` - Выбираем точки
- `(?!(\s)|(\n)|($))` - Где после не (пробел, перенос строки, конец)